# difference between mapM and forM

Tags: haskell, monads

Could you tell me is there exists some difference between `mapM` and `forM` ?
Look at signatures:

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
forM :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
```

The only thing is order of arguments.  It is unvailable, but does it really only difference ?

Comment: No difference but the order of the arguments. `mapM = flip forM`

Comment: you can have [a look](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.Traversable.html#forM) for yourself ;)

Comment: By the way, both are deprecated since GHC 7.10. `for`/`traverse` should be used instead.

Comment: They aren't deprecated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`forM` is defined as `flip mapM` in [`base`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.Traversable.html#forM):

```
-- | 'forM' is 'mapM' with its arguments flipped. For a version that
-- ignores the results see 'Data.Foldable.forM_'.
forM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t a -> (a -> m b) -> m (t b)
{-# INLINE forM #-}
forM = flip mapM
```